# Calling a Function Using DB Link in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, dblink

I have a function (takes 2 parameters) that exists in my source DB and I am trying to call it from another DB using a DB Link. I am using the following code but I keep getting an error:

```
SELECT SCHEMA.FUNC_NAME@DBLINK(PARAM1, PARAM2) FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME@DBLINK;
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
ORA-00904: "SCHEMA"."FUNC_NAME": invalid identifier
```

Comment: Perhaps the user that the db link connects as can't see the function.

Comment: Is it necessary to specifiy a particular table when calling a function? Why not just `SCHEMA.FUNC_NAME@DBLINK(PARAM1, PARAM2) FROM dual;`?

Comment: I got the same error above even with using `dual`

Comment: @samg - it's complaining about the function not the table, so using dual wouldn't help. The user you connect to as part of the database link definition needs to have execute privileges on `schema.func_name` (within the remote DB).

Comment: @samg What is the actual function and schema called? I presume this is just an example you have came up with and not the actual names? I don't think including the schema should do any harm, but I suppose technically the syntax should just be: `FUNC_NAME@DBLINK(PARAM1, PARAM2) FROM dual`.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni - it depends if the function is owned by the same user the DB link connects to. In this case, since the schema is specified and gets an error, they appear to be different. Which is valid, as long as the right privs are in place. (And the function might be being passed values from the remote table, which would explain including that rather than dual. But it's a bit abstract the moment.)

Comment: So if it is a grant privileges issue, how do I go about creating a script that will grant such privileges so that I'm able to call the function using the DBlink?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to rename your database references in my attempt to answer your question.
I will use localDB and remoteDB as database names.
You have a function created on remoteDB.
You should have the DBlink created on localDB.  In the DBLink definition, you have owner, db_link, username, host, and created date. 
On the remoteDB, you need to give select and maybe execute privileges to the username specified in your dblink.
Then, you should be able to execute the function from the localDB using some syntax such as  EXEC SQL CALL schema.func_name@dblink(parm1, parms);